# Adding Foreign Key constraint sucks up memory and causes paging

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having a lot of issues adding a simple foreign key constraint to a newly created empty table. Reference table is a tiny one with less than 40 records in it, but it gets referenced quite a bit.

Here's what happens: new table gets created successfully, but when adding a FK constraint, it "thinks" for a really long time and increases CPU load. Memory usage increases, the server starts paging like crazy and becomes unresponsive (connections time out). Cancelling the query does not help. The only thing that works is rebooting the server, which is very costly.

Here's the script I'm trying to run. I'm hoping SQL server gurus can help out. Thx!

```
USE [my_db]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyNewTable](
    [Column1ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column2ID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyNewTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MyNewTable_Column1ID] FOREIGN KEY([Column1ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ReferenceTable] ([Column1ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyNewTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyNewTable_Column1ID]
GO
```

EDIT: ReferenceTable is a small table that looks something like this:

```
[Column1ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TxtCol1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[TxtCol2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[TxtCol3] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[TxtCol4] [nvarchar](2000) NOT NULL,
[TxtCol5] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[BitCol1] [bit] NOT NULL,
[TxtCol6] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[NumCol1] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[ExternalColumnId] [int] NOT NULL,
[NumCol2] [int] NOT NULL
```

Column1ID is referenced a lot by other tables (FK's). ExternalColumnId is a FK to another table. The problem happens during one of the ALTER TABLE calls. Unfortunately both of those were run together, so I'm unable to say which one caused it.

**EDIT: Once the DB goes into "thinking" mode, it's possible to bring it back up by switching it to single mode and then back to multi user mode. It is much better than rebooting the server but still unacceptable.**

Comment: Strange. What is the definition of `ReferenceTable`? After which statement does it all go wrong? The `ADD  CONSTRAINT` one?

Comment: Just added more info. One thing I did not have in the original table is a primary key. Any idea how much effect that would have, considering the new table is empty?

Comment: Gbn is right and I am pretty sure you are looking at object lock. Was it reproducible. I do not know sqlserver enough, but you could try creating  a new tablespace, served by a datafile in a mounted drive and check if problem exits.(I assume oracle and sql server has parallels ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random thought: do you have any transaction open?

The ALTER TABLE will require exclusive access (as does most DDL) and it could be that it's blocked by a schema lock, which in turn will block ReferenceTable, which in turn will block other queries...

Comment: After consulting with my co-worker, it looks like a DB backup was running at the same time. But considering how tiny the reference table is (~40 records), would it cause such an issue?

Comment: ... I think a lock wouldn't have caused the CPU or the memory usage to rise significatively...

Comment: @pascal: it could do; locks require resources, a long transaction can cause LDF growth, possibly more checkpoint processing, stalled threads being blocked but having their own locks...

Comment: good explanation and I have run across cpu clocks waiting on a stalled thread at least twice ( or more)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest running each query batch in isolation.

First, create the table and see if that succeeds.

Next, try adding the foreign key constraint on its own using `WITH NOCHECK` instead of `WITH CHECK`.  `WITH NOCHECK` will suppress any validation of the content in `MyNewTable.Column1ID` against the values in the column of the referenced table while the constraint is being created.  If `MyNewTable` is empty or has few rows, I wouldn't think that this would have much effect, but I've encountered symptoms like you describe -- except that the table getting the new constraint had millions of rows in it.

Finally, run your last batch to try setting `WITH CHECK` on your new constraint.  If this bogs down, you may just need to leave the new FK set `WITH NOCHECK`, however that isn't recommended since constraints defined `WITH NOCHECK` are ignored by the query optimizer until they are set back to `WITH CHECK`.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is reproducible, I would suggest you to open a Microsoft Support case. May be it's a bug and you are hitting it. If it's found that it's a known issue they would refund you the charges for opening up the case.

Answer (score 0):

A handful of things to look into -- not solutions, but they might lead to something.

Are there any triggers defined?

Is the database being used or accessed at the time you are creating the new table, or is it idle?

Does anything (at time of deployment or otherwise) UPDATE Column1ID in the reference table, or delete rows in that table?

Is there a primary key or unique constraint on on Column1ID in the reference table? (You don't have one listed, but I'd think SQL would fail right off if one wasn't present.)